# MS RemoteApp broken after changing IIS bindings

Tags: remoteapp, remote-desktop-gateway

OS is Server 2008 R2. In an effort to make the internal and external hostnames match (the SSL cert only matches the public hostname), I edited the bindings for our 'RDWeb' site. This somehow broke WelbyApp and I can't seem to undo it. The error I get is:

`Your computer can't connect to the remote computer because the Remote Desktop Gateway server is temporarily unavailable.`

I have downloaded the .RDP file from RemoteApp and opened it with Notepad++: the RD Gateway is correct. Worth noting that the RD Gateway *does still work to RDP into the TS server via RDC 'connect from anywhere.'* Any ideas here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though I still have a mismatch between public and private hostnames, I got RemoteApp working again via instructions here: http://www.concurrency.com/blog/w/remote-desktop-can%E2%80%99t-find-the-computer-through-rdw